# SQL Search - one word less at a time - MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a phrase which I search for in my database, e.g. "Hawthorne Heights - Fragile Future"

This produces 1 result, but, if I search for "Hawthorne Heights" only I get more results.

My question is, is it possible to reduce the terms of a search until I receive the desired number of results or no more.

E.g. initial search

"Hawthorne Heights - Fragile Future"

then

"Hawthorne Heights - Fragile"

then

"Hawthorne Heights"

then

"Hawthorne"

The initial search term could be one word in which case 1 pass is all thats needed, or, it could be ten words.

Is this possible in one query or would I have to reduce the phrase then search again...if so how would I reduce the phrase?

Many thanks for any help.

Below is the code I use currently for the query:

```
$searchTerm = trim($searchTerm);

    $result345 = mysql_query("SELECT main_category, PRid, title, genre, imageURL, lowprice, highprice, prodcatID from PRprodINFO2 where (($title LIKE '%$searchTerm%') AND (imageURL <>'') $is_cat_id) $genre order by $order_col $asc_desc limit 2000",$db);
```

The $variables (e.g. $title, $is_cat_id etc) are dynamic but don't affect the query, its $searchTerm where the phrase is stored

Comment: I can make code for you..if you give me query details. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, in your case you need to create custom query for this. in that case you need to split/explode search keyword with first `"-"` and then `space` (" ").

So at the end of these task you will have all below 6 words with you.

```
For example : 

your search keyword is = "Hawthorne Heights - Fragile Future"

1) Hawthorne Heights
2) Fragile Future.
3) Hawthorne
4) Heights
5) Future
6) Fragile
```

Make one array with complete these all words and create a query in loop. which are having connected with `OR` condition.

**EDITE As per your query:**

```
$searchterm = "Hawthorne Heights - Fragile Future";

$keyword = explode("-",$searchterm);

for($i=0;$i<count($keyword);$i++){
    $word[] = explode(" ",trim($keyword[$i]));
}

for($j=0;$j<count($word);$j++){
    $str[] = implode(',',$word[$j]);
}


$strArr = explode(',',implode(',',$str));

$queryStr = "";
for($cnt = 0;$cnt<count($strArr);$cnt++){
    $queryStr.= "($title LIKE '%".$strArr[$cnt]."%') OR";
}

$searchTerm = substr($queryStr,0,-2);


$result345 = mysql_query("SELECT main_category, PRid, title, genre, imageURL, lowprice, highprice, prodcatID from PRprodINFO2 where (($title LIKE '%$searchterm%'OR $searchTerm) AND (imageURL <>'') $is_cat_id) $genre order by $order_col $asc_desc limit 2000",$db);
```

**These code may have more optimize but because of hurry i make it what me click fast.. :)**

This may helpful to you..let me know if anything else you want to do..

Thanks.